# Location of config.xml in Phonegap Build vs. Visual Studio

Tags: phonegap-build, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Visual Studio 2015 requires config.xml to be placed in the root folder of a project.

Phonegap Build requires that config.xml is placed inside the www folder.

Neither of the two seem to accept the other location of config.xml. How am I able to build using both Visual Studio and Phonegap Build without manually modifying the location of config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to copy the config.xml from one location to the other when building.

This can be done in Visual Studio by editing the .jsproj file and inserting the following MSBuild target:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="config.xml" DestinationFolder="www" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```